# How can I Apply variable "if" to 9th line

Tags: javascript, var, pseudocode

I am working with a wordpress pluguin and i need to apply the variable "if" that correspond to discount in the 9th line:

**(var v = (materias_matricula + materia_info + materia_ingles) / 4 + (nuevo_ingreso);)**

What I'm trying to get is that the result obtained in that line, i can apply the same "if" that I have at the bottom depending on the action that I want to do.

Hope I made it as clear as possible.

```
var nuevo_ingreso = $1;
var materias_matricula = $2;
var materia_info = $3; 
var materia_ingles = $4;
var discount = $5;

var result = materias_matricula + materia_info + materia_ingles + nuevo_ingreso;
var v = result + 22.50;
setSubtotal( 'sub', v );

var v = (materias_matricula + materia_info + materia_ingles) / 4 + (nuevo_ingreso);
setSubtotal( 'subquincena', v );

if (discount == 0) result = result+ 22.50;
if (discount == 1) result = (result + 22.50) * 0.5;


return result;
```

Comment: I don't really understand the question. Is it something other than `if (v == 0) ...`?

Comment: pretty much none of your variables are valid javascript. Are those supposed to be strings? Numbers?

Comment: I want this `if (discount == 0) result = result+ 22.50;
if (discount == 1) result = (result + 22.50) * 0.5;` to be applied in the 9th line `var v = ...`

Comment: Its Pseudo-JS Code